# Running bokeh server programmatically to show in browser locally

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado, bokeh

I am making an interactive data manipulation with `bokeh` (`0.12.6`) utility that I will deploy within a package. The idea is that a user can run a some routine `module.utility()` that will start the bokeh server, launch the application in a browser, and when the tab or browser are closed, the server will be stopped.

My application launches fine if I run `bokeh serve --show myapp`, but it hangs when connecting to the localhost using my method described below. I've inspected the handlers, everything looks as it should.

> Is this a reasonable thing to do, and am I going about it correctly?

**Directory format**

```
<installed module path>/myapp
└── main.py
```

Where `./myapp` will reside in `venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mymodule` etc.

**main.py**

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models.sources import ColumnDataSource

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(x=list(range(5)), y=list(range(5))))

p = figure(width=300, height=300, tools=[], toolbar_location=None)
p.line(x='x', y='y', source=source)

curdoc().add_root(column(p, sizing_mode='scale_width'))
```

**Run script**

```
def run_single_server(abs_app_path, port=5000):
    '''Run bokeh application for single session from server`'''
    from bokeh.application import Application
    from bokeh.application.handlers import DirectoryHandler
    from bokeh.server.server import Server
    import os

    app_name = os.path.split(abs_app_path)[1]
    url = '/{}'.format(app_name)

    # Start a bokeh server
    apps = {url:Application(DirectoryHandler(filename=abs_app_path))}
    server = Server(apps, port=port)
    server.start()
    server.show(url)

    # somehow wait for session to end, perhaps using `server_lifecycle.py`

    server.stop()

    return

def utility():
    import mymodule

    module_path = os.path.split(mymodule.__file__)[0]
    abs_app_path = os.path.join(module_path, 'myapp')

    run_single_server(abs_app_path, port=5000)

    return
```

Perhaps have that routine in the main `__init__.py`, and have it work like this:

```
import mymodule
mymodule.utility()

# 1. Browser launches
# 2. user does stuff
# 3. user closes window
# 4. bokeh server is shutdown
```

---

**Update**
I found the [`build_single_handler_application`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokeh/command/util.py#L40-L76) routine and tried that, but it also appears to hang.

```
from bokeh.command.util import build_single_handler_application
import os

app_name = os.path.split(abs_app_path)[1]
url = '/{}'.format(app_name)

# Start a bokeh server
apps = build_single_handler_application(abs_app_path)
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like I had a couple of problems. I ended up finding and adapting some code that I found on the mail group [here](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!msg/bokeh/LYmjTXzX43E/_0dNPR1_CQAJ) for my use-case.

I managed to get everything to work by using separate process for 1) starting the server, 2) launching the app urls with `webbrowser`, and 3) checking for closed connections and shutting down.

I think I could perhaps do away with initiating the `tornado` server instance as was done in the flask example I adapted, but I'm happy here.

**Note:** this example uses single file apps, but you can pass the paths of directory formatted apps as well.

```
def create_bokeh_server(io_loop, files, argvs, host, port):
    '''Start bokeh server with applications paths'''
    from bokeh.server.server import Server
    from bokeh.command.util import build_single_handler_applications

    # Turn file paths into bokeh apps
    apps = build_single_handler_applications(files, argvs)

    # kwargs lifted from bokeh serve call to Server, with created io_loop
    kwargs = {
        'io_loop':io_loop,
        'generate_session_ids':True,
        'redirect_root':True,
        'use_x_headers':False,
        'secret_key':None,
        'num_procs':1,
        'host': host,
        'sign_sessions':False,
        'develop':False,
        'port':port,
        'use_index':True
    }
    server = Server(apps,**kwargs)

    return server


def run_single_app(files, port=5000, new='tab'):

    def start_bokeh(io_loop):
        '''Start the `io_loop`'''
        io_loop.start()
        return None

    def launch_app(host, app_name, new):
        '''Lauch app in browser

        Ideally this would `bokeh.util.browser.view()`, but it doesn't work
        '''
        import webbrowser

        # Map method strings to webbrowser method
        options = {'current':0, 'window':1, 'tab':2}

        # Concatenate url and open in browser, creating a session
        app_url = 'http://{}/{}'.format(host, app_name)
        print('Opening `{}` in browser'.format(app_url))
        webbrowser.open(app_url, new=options[new])

        return None

    def server_loop(server, io_loop):
        '''Check connections once session created and close on disconnect'''
        import time

        connected = [True,]
        session_loaded = False
        while any(connected):

            # Check if no session started on server
            sessions = server.get_sessions()
            if not session_loaded:
                if sessions:
                    session_loaded = True
            # Once 1+ sessions started, check for no connections
            else:
                # List of bools for each session
                connected = [True,]*len(sessions)
                # Set `connected` item false no connections on session
                for i in range(len(sessions)):
                    if sessions[i].connection_count == 0:
                        connected[i] = False
            # Keep the pace down
            time.sleep(2)

        # Stop server once opened session connections closed
        io_loop.stop()

        return None

    import os
    import threading
    import tornado.ioloop
    import tornado.autoreload
    import time

    # Initialize some values, sanatize the paths to the bokeh plots
    argvs = {}
    app_names = []
    for path in files:
        argvs[path] = None
        app_names.append(os.path.splitext(os.path.split(path)[1])[0])

    # Concate hostname/port for creating handlers, launching apps
    host = 'localhost:{}'.format(port)

    # Initialize the tornado server
    io_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
    tornado.autoreload.start(io_loop)

    # Add the io_loop to the bokeh server
    server = run_bokeh_server(io_loop, files, argvs, host, port)

    print('Starting the server on {}'.format(host))
    args = (io_loop,)
    th_startup = threading.Thread(target=start_bokeh, args=args)
    th_startup.start()

    # Launch each application in own tab or window
    th_launch = [None,]*len(app_names)
    for i in range(len(app_names)):
        args = (host, app_names[i], new)
        th_launch[i] = threading.Thread(target=launch_app, args=args)
        th_launch[i].start()
        # Delay to allow tabs to open in same browser window
        time.sleep(2)

    # Run session connection test, then stop `io_loop`
    args = (server, io_loop)
    th_shutdown = threading.Thread(target=server_loop, args=args)
    th_shutdown.start()

    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":

import os
files = [os.path.join('bokeh', fname) for fname in ['ex1.py','ex2.py']]
run_single_app(files, port=5006)
```

Comment: Where did you find the documentation for 'use_x_headers':False? After extensive Googling, this is the only page I have found that mentions it.

Comment: I don't recall, but my guess is that I got that from the code I found on the Google mailing list that I adapted.